# How to save the bytes received from a datagram socket in python as a .wav file?

Tags: python, sockets, audio, pyaudio, datagram

I have written the following code which receives audio data in bytes from an Android(Java) client and outputs it through the speaker. I want to **combine the bytes received** and save them in .wav file of 5 seconds each.

```
import pyaudio
import numpy as np
import time
import io
from pprint import pprint
import scipy.io.wavfile

p = pyaudio.PyAudio()


stream = p.open(format=pyaudio.paInt16,
                channels=1,
                rate=16000,
                output=True)


host ='192.168.1.1'
print(host)
port = 50005 

server_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_DGRAM)  
server_socket.bind((host, port))  


data, addr = server_socket.recvfrom(1280) 

try:
    while data != '':
        stream.write(data)
        data, addr = server_socket.recvfrom(1280) 

except KeyboardInterrupt:
    pass


stream.stop_stream()
stream.close()
```

Comment: `frames` is undefined in your code

Comment: sorry for that. I have edited the code @RomanPerekhrest

Comment: You can use [SoundFile.buffer_write()](https://pysoundfile.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#soundfile.SoundFile.buffer_write) (with `dtype='int16'` for your example) to write the bytes directly to a `SoundFile`.